# Water in glass tubes producing different pitches when tapped. Why exactly is this?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, acoustics

So I've been making a DIY instrument for my physics project at school. I decided to try this experiment where I put different volumes of water into a glass cup, and I tap it with a spoon to create different sounds. The goal is to make a song out of it. Anyway, I would like a good explanation on how sound is produced when I tap the cup, and why the pitch varies when different volumes of water is inside the cup.

Cheers

Comment: To add, it is the pitch of the fundamental frequency that you usually tend to hear when tapping the glass.

Comment: Have you tried searching the internet for an answer?  The following is #3 in a google search of your exact title :  http://www.stevespanglerscience.com/lab/experiments/pop-bottle-sounds/  What exactly is a "good" explanation?

Comment: Actually, I've obviously tried googling. That link doesn't come up in the top hit when I search it. Not even on the 1st page. Thx anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Water in a glass cup can be thought of as a one end closed organ pipe. The more volume of water you add, you effectively increase the length of the water column thereby reducing the length of the air column. The frequency is dependent on the length which can be understood from the following diagram.

[image: water in a pipe]
As you can see the length of the air column changes because of which the frequency changes.
$$\nu=n\frac{\nu_0}{4L}$$, where $\nu_0 $ is the fundamental frequency. Thus various lengths produce different frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

By changing the amount of water in a tube you are changing the effective length of the tube. When you create a sound wave in the air inside the tube, the wave is reflected at the water surface and at the open end. With waves initially traveling in both directions inside the tube, they interfere with themselves and form standing waves. These standing waves cannot have any frequency (or wavelength). Since the tube has one end closed (the water surface) and one end open the resonance frequencies are given by 
$$f_n=\frac{nf_0}{4L},$$
where $f_0$ is the frequency of the fundamental (first) harmonic, $L$ is the length of the tube and $n$ is an odd positive integer.

Comment: @philip_0008 Thanks, you are totally right!

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, the fundamental frequency can be obtained by:
$$f_0 = v_s/\lambda_0$$
Where $v_s$ is the speed of sound, and $\lambda_0 = 4L$ where $L$ is the length of the air column in the tube.

so, 
$$f_0 = v_s/\lambda_0 = \frac{v_s}{4L}$$
and so, 
$$f_n = \frac{nf_0}{4L} = \frac{n}{4L}\frac{v_s}{4L} = \frac{nv_s}{16L^2}$$